# Desktop refreshing icons every 15 seconds or so

Tags: macos, desktop, icon, refresh

I've been on Mavericks since it was open to the general public.

But yesterday it started frequently refreshing he desktop icons, over and over again, possibly every 10-15 seconds.  It's very strange.

I'm not moving any windows or moving the mouse around.  Often I'm just reading a web page or some email and I'll notice the desktop repaint all the icons, then read a bit more, then notice it doing it again.

Macbook Pro retina, Mavericks.  Have noticed on 2 extern displays (Apple Thunderbolt display at work and on 1080p TV/monitor at home).  Laptop itself is typically closed.

I've posted other questions about desktop icon placement, not sure if any of that is related, just full disclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Just searched for people that have this problem, because I had the same problem today. After searching the internet for about half an hour I found a little post that was old and short on Apple forum.

I guy said it is Google Drive that triggers it. I uninstalled Google Drive, and WOW my problem was gone.

So if you are a Google Drive user, try to uninstall (reinstall) and see. I say reinstall because I have had Google Drive on my Mac before without the problem, but for now, I have it totally uninstalled.

NOTE: I did uninstall with a software for the purpose, I'm using AppZapper, but there are many others of that sort. I also deleted the .DS_Store file on desktop (just in case it was corrupted). If you want to delete the .DS_Store file, you need to have hidden files shown (or use the Terminal) on your mac.

Comment: I DO use Google Drive, so this is very likely.  However, now the desktop isn't doing it anymore so I really can't test (so hesitant on the green checkmark because I can't 100% verify it, not sure the policy on that)

Answer (score 1):

Mine was doing it too, although it wouldn't refresh the icons for files that I downloaded (i.e., if I downloaded a .zip file, it would just show the intermediate loading icon).

I don't use Google Drive for the Mac, but have read that for those instances to avoid uninstalling, all you have to do is (as of right now) go to Google Drive preferences and disable the «Show file sync status icons and right click menu».

I personally deleted the .DS_Store file as @JW_ mentioned and everything is back to normal (for now)! Beautiful!